# Export asp.net page to pdf issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf

To export a page to Pdf I found code from google. After exporting I am getting the additional info into pdf file.

```
 Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            this.Page.RenderControl(hw);
            StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
            Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
            HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            htmlparser.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.Write(pdfDoc);                
            Response.Flush();
```

**The following additional info shows into my pdf file at the bottom.**

//var theForm = document.forms['form1']; if (!theForm) { theForm = document.form1; } function
__doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) { if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget; theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
theForm.submit(); } } //

How can I get rid of above additional info during exporting page to Pdf?

Any kind of hints or sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: try adding this line before `Response.Clear()`
this one `Response.ContentType` also don't forget to add `Response.End() and Response.Close()`

Comment: I followed your instruction but does not resolve that issue. Any other solution?

Comment: where is the link that you found the code that you're using.. perhaps you are using broken code to begin with can you provide the link so we can see

Comment: Editable Grid view link : https://www.codeproject.com/kb/webforms/editgridviewcells.aspx             Convert this page to Pdf link:  https://www.codeproject.com/tips/648160/export-web-page-with-images-to-pdf

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try to delete AllowPaging="true" and AllowSorting="true" from your asp gridview in aspx file. My problem is solved.